# Complex Symfony2 Form Builder

Tags: ajax, symfony, post, formbuilder

I have an application where a game is played on a tablet device and if score is high enough it does an ajax post passing the score to a Symfony2 form where the user enters their name.

The issue I have is that the Symfony2 form thinks the form itself has already been submitted and so produces an error.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
or if there is a better way of doing this?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Without any code or more information it will be hard to help you...

Comment: Need code, most likely you're binding the form and submitting it. You're supposed to use either or.